# Why does llvm::SmallVector split its storage?

Tags: c++, vector, llvm

The implementation of `llvm::SmallVector<T,N>` is split amongst many types:

- [`llvm::SmallVectorBase`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h#L39) holds 3 `void*`s for begin, end, and capacity.
- [`llvm::SmallVectorTemplateCommon<T>`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h#L75) holds the *first* element of the small storage, as an appropriately aligned and sized `char` array.
- [`llvm::SmallVector<T,N>`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h#L845) holds the next `N-1` elements of the small storage, as an array of appropriately aligned and sized `char`arrays.

Why is the storage split between the two class templates, as opposed to having the most derived class (`SmallVector<T,N>`) simply store all `N` elements and pass in pointers to this storage down to the base class? That is, where currently the default constructor does:

```
SmallVector() : SmallVectorImpl<T>(N) { }
```

A hypothetical different implementation could do:

```
SmallVector() : SmallVectorImpl<T>(&Storage, T * sizeof(N)) { }
```

and `SmallVectorTemplateCommon` would not have the `FirstEl` member. What is the advantage of the implementation as it stands?

Comment: A `SmallVector` isn't always small, so you need a way to get a pointer to the small storage independent of `begin`. That's conveniently available as `&firstEl`.

Comment: @T.C. Why would you need it?

Comment: How do you tell if the vector is currently in small mode without it (or some equivalent info)?

Comment: @T.C. Why does that middle type in the hierarchy need that info tho?

Comment: Because all the common operations - which don't otherwise depend on the size of the small storage - need it? e.g., reallocation: you need to know if you are in small mode because you need to free the original storage, but you don't care exactly how big the small storage is.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, that sounds like the answer then?

Comment: @T.C. Couldn't that middle type just check if `begin()` pointed to like `this` (offset appropriately)?

Comment: and get the offset *just* right considering possible padding due to alignment etc.? Somehow that sounds far trickier to maintain.

Comment: @T.C. As opposed to an array that's split between two types? One doesn't seem inherently worse than the other to me at first glance.

Comment: So you want to compute the alignment, calculate the correct padding, all of which are platform- and possibly compiler-dependent, and recalculate all that again should you need to add an extra data member, instead of having the compiler do all that for you. Hmm. OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141683/discussion-between-barry-and-t-c).

Comment: IIRC [Chandler covers some of this in this CPPcon 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vElZc6zSIXM)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The code Chandler shows there is what I'd [naively] expect `SmallVector` to look like (the derived type has the full N elements), but that's not what the code actually looks like.

Answer (score 6):

Splitting the storage avoids storing the inline capacity (or an "is small" bit) in the "size-erased" type `SmallVectorImpl`.

`SmallVectorImpl<T>` can be used to reference any `SmallVector<T, N>` and supports all vector operations on it. When the the underlying storage grows the pointer cannot be passed to `free` if it's using the inline capacity. Comparing the current storage's address to the first element of the inline capacity is convenient and saves a bit of memory in SmallVector.